# Combining fields to make a unique record or keeping them separated

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, uniqueidentifier

I've been asked to implement what has before, been a bunch of CSV files, into a MySQL database.  I'm at a point in the design where all the schemas, tables and fields have been mocked-up; however I'm hesitating about how to approach one particular part, especially with regards to read-ability (of eventual queries), flexibility and scalability.

**A little background first:**

We are collecting DNA samples from various types of animals (e.g. pigs/mice) [*In the future, I can see us adding more animals.*]; we need to keep track of metadata both for the actual sample that was collected as well as the animal.  Each animal has an ID (not defined by us), however it is not unique, and both a mouse and a pig could conceivably have the same ID.  Furthermore, each sample from a particular animal belongs to a sample set.  IDs for the sample are recycled (and thus non-unique), however the sample set ID is never recycled [thus the combination of sample ID & sample set ID is unique].

I will have several tables that will include fields with the AnimalID and others with the sampleID.

**How I'm imagining settings things up:**

- for each of the tables that require animal information, I'll have (among others) the fields: AnimalID & AnimalType (e.g. mouse/pig)
- for each of the tables that require sample information, I'll have (among others) the fields: SampleID & SampleSet

The problem with this, is that if I want to join across tables, I'll have to join across two fields.  However, I could use the SampleSet and AnimalType as foreign keys for lookup tables & it makes retrieving a particular set or animal type very straightforward.

**An alternative approach:**

- for each of the tables that require animal information, I'll have a field (among others) that combines the AnimalID & Type together.  So I could have something like P### for a pig or M### for a mouse.
- for each of the tables that require animal information, I'll have a field (among others) that combines the SampleID & Set together.  So I could have something like A### for sample set A.

The problem with this is that it's not as straightforward to select (for example) all the samples from a particular set (although of course you could query with a: `where sampleID like "A%"`; however it makes joining across tables straightforward.

So, which is the "better" more flexible approach?  Perhaps there is another approach that could leverage the advantages of both approaches?

Comment: I suggest you don't combine character codes with numerical (IDs). You can always join on two (or more) columns and use composite indexes.

Comment: As @ypercube said, you should leave the data in the structured format it is already in.  Simply not wanting to have to JOIN on two fields is no reason to combine data that you may in fact *need* separately in future.

Comment: Thanks guys; the composite indices was the part I was missing.

Comment: Depending on how large the table is and how many indexes you eventually add, you may wish to "invent" a new key that is the hash values of the columns that form a unique key. If you pick the hash function right, you can nearly guarantee there will be no collisions.

Comment: Rather than the abstruse term "AnimalType" why not use "species"?

Comment: @MichaelGreen great suggestion!

Comment: I'd suggest normalizing the database a bit more. Rather than using AnimalID and AnimalType as a unique key, create an autonumber column as primary key, e.g. "AnimalKey" and let the database assign an internally consistent identifier which would be used as the foreign key. For each animal, there should be only one row in one table containing AnimalID and AnimalType and other tables would reference the animal by AnimalKey. Same applies to SampleSetID/SampleID.

Comment: @dartonw yep, after some more research, I'm going to take this approach of using a surrogate key for both the animals and samples